# Python- Downloading a file from a webpage by clicking on a link

Tags: python, html

I've looked around the internet for a solution to this but none have really seemed applicable here. I'm writing a Python program to predict the next day's stock price using historical data. I don't need all the historical data since inception as Yahoo finance provides but only the last 60 days or so. The NASDAQ website provides just the right amount of historical data and I wanted to use that website.

What I want to do is, go to a particular stock's profile on NASDAQ. For Example: (www.nasdaq.com/symbol/amd/historical) and click on the "Download this File in Excel Format" link at the very bottom. I inspected the page's HTML to see if there was an actual link I can just use with urllib to get the file but all I got was:

```
<a id="lnkDownLoad" href="javascript:getQuotes(true);">
                Download this file in Excel Format
            </a>
```

No link. So my question is,how can I write a Python script that goes to a given stock's NASDAQ page, click on the Download file in excel format link and actually download the file from it. Most solutions online require you to know the url where the file is stored but in this case, I don't have access to that. So how do I go about doing this?

Comment: Google "python selenium"

Comment: From what I'm reading about it, it helps me interact with the web browser as in it will actually open up the web browser. I would like to do it more behind the scenes where the file simply gets downloaded to a specified destination

Comment: Do you need only the 3-month data that is provided by default?

Comment: If you use the PhantomJS webdriver, it doesn't need to open a browser.

Comment: @BillBell Yes only the last 3 months. Doing some machine learning so data that is 20 years old isn't that helpful. Need more current data

Comment: Just added an alternate method to Selenium as an answer.

Comment: What the comments and answers are hinting at is that this webpage uses javascript to rewrite itself when you load it in a browser. Since it doesn't seem that you understood this when you wrote this question, you'll have a hard time working around any intentional obfuscation thrown at you by the site designers. If you're lucky and the site is simply using straightforward AJAX, Julien's answer might just be enough to get you there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that BeautifulSoup might be the easiest way to do this. I've made a cursory check that the results of the following script are the same as those that appear on the page. You would just have to write the results to a file, rather than print them. However, the columns are ordered differently.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/amd/historical'
page = requests.get(URL).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
tableDiv = soup.find_all('div', id="historicalContainer")
tableRows = tableDiv[0].findAll('tr')

for tableRow in tableRows[2:]:
    row = tuple(tableRow.getText().split())
    print ('"%s",%s,%s,%s,%s,"%s"' % row)
```

Output:

```
"03/24/2017",14.16,14.18,13.54,13.7,"50,022,400"
"03/23/2017",13.96,14.115,13.77,13.79,"44,402,540"
"03/22/2017",13.7,14.145,13.55,14.1,"61,120,500"
"03/21/2017",14.4,14.49,13.78,13.82,"72,373,080"
"03/20/2017",13.68,14.5,13.54,14.4,"91,009,110"
"03/17/2017",13.62,13.74,13.36,13.49,"224,761,700"
"03/16/2017",13.79,13.88,13.65,13.65,"44,356,700"
"03/15/2017",14.03,14.06,13.62,13.98,"55,070,770"
"03/14/2017",14,14.15,13.6401,14.1,"52,355,490"
"03/13/2017",14.475,14.68,14.18,14.28,"72,917,550"
"03/10/2017",13.5,13.93,13.45,13.91,"62,426,240"
"03/09/2017",13.45,13.45,13.11,13.33,"45,122,590"
"03/08/2017",13.25,13.55,13.1,13.22,"71,231,410"
"03/07/2017",13.07,13.37,12.79,13.05,"76,518,390"
"03/06/2017",13,13.34,12.38,13.04,"117,044,000"
"03/03/2017",13.55,13.58,12.79,13.03,"163,489,100"
"03/02/2017",14.59,14.78,13.87,13.9,"103,970,100"
"03/01/2017",15.08,15.09,14.52,14.96,"73,311,380"
"02/28/2017",15.45,15.55,14.35,14.46,"141,638,700"
"02/27/2017",14.27,15.35,14.27,15.2,"95,126,330"
"02/24/2017",14,14.32,13.86,14.12,"46,130,900"
"02/23/2017",14.2,14.45,13.82,14.32,"79,900,450"
"02/22/2017",14.3,14.5,14.04,14.28,"71,394,390"
"02/21/2017",13.41,14.1,13.4,14,"66,250,920"
"02/17/2017",12.79,13.14,12.6,13.13,"40,831,730"
"02/16/2017",13.25,13.35,12.84,12.97,"52,403,840"
"02/15/2017",13.2,13.44,13.15,13.3,"33,655,580"
"02/14/2017",13.43,13.49,13.19,13.26,"40,436,710"
"02/13/2017",13.7,13.95,13.38,13.49,"57,231,080"
"02/10/2017",13.86,13.86,13.25,13.58,"54,522,240"
"02/09/2017",13.78,13.89,13.4,13.42,"72,826,820"
"02/08/2017",13.21,13.75,13.08,13.56,"75,894,880"
"02/07/2017",14.05,14.27,13.06,13.29,"158,507,200"
"02/06/2017",12.46,13.7,12.38,13.63,"139,921,700"
"02/03/2017",12.37,12.5,12.04,12.24,"59,981,710"
"02/02/2017",11.98,12.66,11.95,12.28,"116,246,800"
"02/01/2017",10.9,12.14,10.81,12.06,"165,784,500"
"01/31/2017",10.6,10.67,10.22,10.37,"51,993,490"
"01/30/2017",10.62,10.68,10.3,10.61,"37,648,430"
"01/27/2017",10.6,10.73,10.52,10.67,"32,563,480"
"01/26/2017",10.35,10.66,10.3,10.52,"35,779,140"
"01/25/2017",10.74,10.975,10.15,10.35,"61,800,440"
"01/24/2017",9.95,10.49,9.95,10.44,"43,858,900"
"01/23/2017",9.68,10.06,9.68,9.91,"27,848,180"
"01/20/2017",9.88,9.96,9.67,9.75,"27,936,610"
"01/19/2017",9.92,10.25,9.75,9.77,"46,087,250"
"01/18/2017",9.54,10.1,9.42,9.88,"51,705,580"
"01/17/2017",10.17,10.23,9.78,9.82,"70,388,000"
"01/13/2017",10.79,10.87,10.56,10.58,"38,344,340"
"01/12/2017",10.98,11.0376,10.33,10.76,"75,178,900"
"01/11/2017",11.39,11.41,11.15,11.2,"39,337,330"
"01/10/2017",11.55,11.63,11.33,11.44,"29,122,540"
"01/09/2017",11.37,11.64,11.31,11.49,"37,215,840"
"01/06/2017",11.29,11.49,11.11,11.32,"34,437,560"
"01/05/2017",11.43,11.69,11.23,11.24,"38,777,380"
"01/04/2017",11.45,11.5204,11.235,11.43,"40,742,680"
"01/03/2017",11.42,11.65,11.02,11.43,"55,114,820"
"12/30/2016",11.7,11.78,11.25,11.34,"44,033,460"
"12/29/2016",11.24,11.62,11.01,11.59,"50,180,310"
"12/28/2016",12.28,12.42,11.46,11.55,"71,072,640"
"12/27/2016",11.65,12.08,11.6,12.07,"44,168,130"
```

The script escapes dates and thousands-separated numbers.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for. I don't know why I didn't consider getting the information from the table itself rather than being fixated on downloading the file. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

1. Using Chrome, go to `View > Developer > Developer Tools`
2. In this new developer tools UI, change to the `Network` tab
3. Navigate to the place where you would need to click, and click the  ⃠ symbol to clear all recent activity.
4. Click the link, and see if there was any requests made to the server
5. If there was, click it, and see if you can reverse engineer the API of its endpoint

**Please be aware that this may be against the website's Terms of Service!**

Answer (score 0):

Dig a little bit deeper and find out what js function `getQuotes()` does. You should get a good clue from that.

If it all seem too much complicated, then you can always use selenium. It is used to simulate the browser. However, it is much slower than using native network calls. You can find official documentation [here](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/).