# Python: download a file from a clickable link that when clicked starts downloading

Tags: python, file, url, download

I have a URL link that if I click on it, it will start downloading a file. 
The URL looks something like this:

```
http://somewebsite.com/download?f=someStrings
```

If I copy the URL and past it, in the URL bar of a web-browser it will start downloading as well.

How can I download the file using Python and preferably without using selenium.

Comment: It might be a matter of handling a redirect and/or setting correct request headers such as user agent. Could you share the real url?

Comment: Look into requests module

Comment: @lone_ranger I know using requests how to read the content of a webpage, but how to download a file?

Comment: @COVFEFE-19, unfortunately, I cannot. But can you please point me to a reference?

Comment: What does it return if you do requests.get()? Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43020352/python-downloading-a-file-from-a-webpage-by-clicking-on-a-link

Comment: @lone_ranger it returns status 200. But I don't see any file downloaded.

Comment: you need to do something like
import requests
import json
res = requests.get(url)
print(res.json())

Answer (score 1):

You can download the file using the `requests` module:

```py
import requests as rq
r = rq.get('http://somewebsite.com/download?f=someStrings', allow_redirects=True)
open('filename.extension', 'wb').write(r.content)
```

**Some points to note:**

1. Replace `http://somewebsite.com/download?f=someStrings` with your desired URL
2. Replace `filename.extension` with file name and its file extension.
3. You can also specify the path where you want to save it